# Beamer: Hyperref moves to wrong position in target frame. Where is the "error"?

Tags: beamer, hyperref, labels, hypertarget

I want to navigate to specific frames in my document, using hyperlink and labels.
In the attached code, when viewing the PDF (with okular or evince) in a small viewer window that fits exactly one page, the links land on target frame *below* the frame title.
When viewing in full-screen presentation mode, the link lands correctly and displays the frame title as well.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[t,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\useoutertheme{infolines} %broader lines than Malmoe standard
\usetheme{Luebeck} %Malmoe/Luebeck inverts colours in headers and title 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Contents}
\begin{itemize}
\item \hyperlink{NV}{goto next slide}
\item \hyperlink{NV2}{goto third slide}
\item \hyperlink{NV3}{goto last slide}
\end{itemize}
\vspace{2mm}
\begin{center}
next...
\end{center}
\end{frame}
%-----------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{frame}[label=NV]{Title}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item this is the first line below the title
 \end{itemize}
\vspace{2mm} 
\begin{center}
 next...
\end{center}
\end{frame}
%-----------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{frame}[label=NV2]{Title 2}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item this is the first line below the title
 \end{itemize}
\vspace{2mm} 
\begin{center}
 next...
\end{center}
\end{frame}
%-----------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{frame}[label=NV3]{Title 3}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item this is the first line below the title
 \end{itemize}
\vspace{2mm} 
\begin{center}
 end
\end{center}
\end{frame}
%-----------------------------------------------------------%
\end{document}
```

Usage:

> pdflatex myfile.tex
> okular myfile.pdf

Adjust okular window to display just one page and
click on links to page 2 or 3.
Page 4 links properly but on the other hand there is no way
to show anything lying "after" the last frame.

Any clues?